Does Independence Given C and independence given D Imply Independence Given C ∩ D
Suppose that A and B are independent conditional on C, and that A and B are also
independent conditional on D. Are events A and B independent conditional on (C ∩ D)? Either prove this theorem or provide a counter-example.
I spent 4 hours working on this question and still have no clue.I tried to find a counter-example, but it's quite challenging, given there are four different events.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

The conditions of the problem define a bunch of equations. You can start by writing them. You might find a diagram useful to keep track of the events.

Here is a counterexample.
Roll a $24$-sided (fair) die, or equivalently, consider $X\sim \mathcal{U}(1,\dots,24)$. Let $A$, $B$, $C$ and $D$ be the following events:
$A=\{X\text{ is even}\}$
$B=\{X\text{ is a multiple of }3\}$
$C=\{1\leqslant X\leqslant 12\}$
$D=\{4\leqslant X\leqslant 15\}$

Fact 1: conditionally to $C$, $A$ and $B$ are independent.
proof. We compute the following quantities:
$$\mathbb P(A|C)=\frac{\mathbb P(X\in\{2,4,6,8,10,12\})}{\mathbb P(X\in\{1,\dots,12\})}=\frac{6}{12}=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\mathbb P(B|C)=\frac{\mathbb P(X\in\{3,6,9,12\})}{\mathbb P(X\in\{1,\dots,12\})}=\frac{4}{12}=\frac{1}{3}$$
$$\mathbb P(A\cap B|C)=\frac{\mathbb P(X\in\{6,12\})}{\mathbb P(X\in\{1,\dots, 12\})}=\frac{2}{12}=\frac{1}{6}$$
Hence
$$\mathbb P(A\cap B|C)=\mathbb P(A|C)\mathbb P(B|C)$$
and conditionally to $C$, $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Fact 2: conditionally to $D$, $A$ and $B$ are independent.
proof. We compute the following quantities:
$$\mathbb P(A|D)=\frac{\mathbb P(X\in\{4,6,8,10,12,14\})}{\mathbb P(X\in\{4,\dots,15\})}=\frac{6}{12}=\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\mathbb P(B|D)=\frac{\mathbb P(X\in\{6,9,12,15\})}{\mathbb P(X\in\{4,\dots,15\})}=\frac{4}{12}=\frac{1}{3}$$
$$\mathbb P(A\cap B|D)=\frac{\mathbb P(X\in\{6,12\})}{\mathbb P(X\in\{4,\dots,15\})}=\frac{2}{12}=\frac{1}{6}$$
Notice that
$$\mathbb P(A\cap B|D)=\mathbb P(A|D)\mathbb P(B|D)$$
which means that conditionally to $D$, $A$ and $B$ are independent.

Fact 3: conditionally to $C\cap D$, $A$ and $B$ are not independent.
proof. We get the following probabilities:
$$\mathbb P(A|C\cap D)=\frac{\mathbb P(X\in\{4,6,8,10,12\})}{\mathbb P(X\in\{4,\dots,12\})}=\frac{5}{9}$$
$$\mathbb P(B|C\cap D)=\frac{\mathbb P(X\in\{6,9,12\})}{\mathbb P(X\in\{4,\dots,12\})}=\frac{3}{9}=\frac{1}{3}$$
$$\mathbb P(A\cap B|C\cap D)=\frac{\mathbb P(X\in\{6,12\})}{\mathbb P(X\in\{4,\dots,12\})}=\frac{2}{9}$$
Note that
$$\mathbb P(A\cap B|C\cap D)\ne \mathbb P(A|C\cap D)\mathbb P(B|C\cap D)$$

Of course there might be easier counterexamples.

Thank you so much! May I ask what is your thought framework when you construct this answer? Also, I think there is a typo in "Fact 2": the probability of A intersecting B condition on D should be 2/12 instead of 1/12.

Thank you for noticing, I edited my answer.

I don't have a general method to construct counterexample... I had to give 4 events, so I thought it would be easier to work on a cardinal $24=4!$ set. I already knew that, conditionnally to a set ${k,\dots,k+2\times 3 -1}$, $A$ and $B$ would be independent. I just had to find two such sets that intersect on a set whose size is not a multiple of $2\times 3 =6$. Found those ones!
